# What is the simplest way to handle too many cases when calculating shipping fees?

Tags: algorithm

i am building a system that allows sellers to setup shipping fee.

The sellers can set shipping fee for 1 item by choosing 1 of these options:

```
-0$ (no shipping fee)
-a fixed local shipping fee
-a fixed international shipping fee
-a flat local shipping fee
-a flat international shipping fee
-TBCL (to be calculated later)
```

The buyer has his/her own address & can buy many items (all items must belongs to 1 seller) per order. & different items may have different shipping fee options.

Too many combinations can happen. Ex,  a Buyer in Australia buy many items (it could be 0$, fixed or flat fee) from a seller in USA,

So what is the best & simplest way to handle this complexity?

Comment: What do you mean by "too many combinations"? This seems like a "pick one" case.

Comment: I would say by using a design pattern, and what about [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)?

Comment: how to calculate shipping fee with many different combinations ?

Comment: usually by adding the fees for the different items?

Comment: Do you mean like "A buyer in australia buys 6 items from USA, each with it's own shipping fee rule?"

Comment: it depends, buyer can buy 2 items in Aus , these 2 items can have the same rules or different rules, nothing is known by advanced except that we know buyer can only have oder from the same seller

Comment: if add the fee to different items then how we can calculate the TBCL case?

Comment: also for the flat fee, seller only charge the same flat fee no matter how many items the customer buy

Comment: Are you using Java, PHP, C++ and VB.NET at the same time?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for help planning out the logic, rather than having a specific technical problem, if I understand you correctly.  The problem is, without knowing your requirement spec, I'm not sure how anyone can help.

Surely calculating the shipping fee would just involve totaling up the shipping fees for each item(?)  If so; each item could be an object in a list of objects, with its own shipping fee just a property.  

Consider having an Order object as a root list with Item objects as its children, and a Total Shipping Fee property.

Comment: i use Java only, but the logic can be the same for any lang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Strategy design pattern from the GOF[1] would fit well in this case.

You would define an `ShippingFeeStrategy` interface with a method like `calculateShipping(deliveryAddress)`. You would then implement various classes that realize this interface (like `NoShippingFeeStrategy` and `FixedLocalShippingFeeStrategy`), each one implementing the `calculateShipping()` method accordingly.

Every item or seller (according to how you model your system) would have an associated instance of `ShippingFeeStrategy`, which would be requested to do the calculation whenever needed.

A similar example can be found in http://www.dofactory.com/javascript-strategy-pattern.aspx, which calculates shipping fees according to the selected shipping method.

[1]: Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson,John Vlissides - **Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software** (Addison-Wesley, ISBN: 0-201-63361-2)

Comment: great answer, u made the difference